# $\gamma^5$ in the SymPy HEP package

Tags: particle-physics, computational-physics, software

As far as I can tell, the fifth [gamma matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) is missing from SymPy's tools for working with gamma matrices: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/hep/index.html. Is there a workaround for this? I tried using a relation with the Levi-Civita tensor, however this requires multiplying with $i$, which throws an error. The module seems very limited if there is no way to represent $\gamma^5$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be about coding, not physics.

Comment: Martin, here is PSE’s policy on coding questions: “Implementation details of computational tasks are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site. While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic. It may be suitable for Computational Science or Stack Overflow, however.”

Comment: If you think there is an issue, I would suggest creating an issue on their github page to discuss with their team. (I know nothing about sympy :P)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the "workaround":

$$ \gamma^5=i\gamma^0\gamma^1\gamma^2\gamma^3 $$

by definition?

Comment: Sympy uses the abstract index calss, which means i do not think there is a way to do this. You can't use non-symbolic indises.  I tried $i/4 \epsilon_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma$, but this does not work.